# ASP Page Request Count

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have this ASP Page and on every request i want to add the  count value by 1 and show the value and also keep the count value in a text stream here's my code but the problem is there is nothing in my txt file after loading the page

```
<script runat="server">

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.IO.StreamWriter sw;
    System.IO.StreamReader sr ;
    int count=0;
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(@"filepath\ResponsCount.txt"))
    {
        sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"filepath\ResponsCount.txt");
        sw.WriteLine("count.ToString()");
    }

    else
    {
        sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"filepath\ResponsCount.txt");
        count = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
        count++;
        sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"filepath\ResponsCount.txt");
        sw.WriteLine(count.ToString());
    }
    Label2.Text = count.ToString();
}
</script>
```

Comment: you don't seem to close the stream writer.... should be sw.Close();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see you closing the streamwriter...

```
sw.Close();
```

is what you should do when you have written to the file.
This then flushes everything to the file that is being written and finally closes it correctly.